# Fit a Weibull distribution to...right-censored data?

Tags: r, survival, censoring, weibull-distribution

Premise: I know next to nothing about survival analysis, I just started. I have a vector of failure times for some machines. Most of the machines (3362 vs 2694) are still running today, so I know they haven't failed, and the failure time is at some unknown time in the future. If I'm not mistaken, we call this *right-censored* data. Correct? Now, I would like to start simple and fit a Weibull distribution to these data. No regression, no covariates - just fit a distribution to these data, and see what it looks like. Is this possible? What are the methods used to fit a Weibull distribution to right-censored data, and are there some of these methods available in R?

**EDIT** adding a data sample to show what I would like to do

```
# sample data set
foo <- structure(list(time = c(416L, 307L, 552L, 740L, 1126L, 442L, 
765L, 375L, 275L, 623L, 455L, 695L, 724L, 1653L, 529L, 615L, 
15L, 477L, 758L, 353L, 851L, 25L, 524L, 283L, 954L, 183L, 558L, 
851L, 377L, 208L), event = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)), .Names = c("time", 
"event"), row.names = c(1170L, 5856L, 1237L, 1448L, 1161L, 4759L, 
2766L, 3321L, 4253L, 5645L, 3875L, 3531L, 238L, 3204L, 714L, 
2161L, 3275L, 5879L, 3758L, 2406L, 1548L, 4234L, 87L, 2548L, 
3958L, 5872L, 3326L, 1549L, 4823L, 1002L), class = "data.frame")

# fit a Weibull distribution
weibull_fit <- survreg(Surv(time, event) ~ 1, data = foo)
summary(weibull_fit)

# Call:
# survreg(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ 1, data = foo)
#             Value Std. Error     z        p
# (Intercept)  6.881      0.132 52.14 0.000000
# Log(scale)  -0.758      0.197 -3.86 0.000115
#
# Scale= 0.469 
# 
# Weibull distribution
# Loglik(model)= -101.2   Loglik(intercept only)= -101.2
# Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 8 
# n= 30
```

R fits the distribution, which is what I wanted. But I hoped there would be some function to plot the survival function, with confidence bounds...it looks like there's none.

**EDIT2** for those interested in a simple intro to Survival Analysis, this page is short but sweet:
http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7s1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fitting is implemented in R's classic `survival` package [(this function)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/survreg.html), or `flexsurv`, which has more flexibility, but a different parametrization for Weibull (`flexsurvreg` function [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/flexsurv.pdf)). Both also provide a few other distributions to try out.

Although I am not entirely sure about the method, it looks like both packages use likelihood maximization (from inspection of source functions, e.g. `body(flexsurv::flexsurvreg)`).

---

For more detailed R instructions and plotting examples, see [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151591/how-to-plot-the-survival-curve-generated-by-survreg-package-survival-of-r). The idea there is to take various survival fractions $S(t)$, use `predict.survreg` as $S^{-1}(t)$ to get the corresponding times, and plot those on your own. In the no-covariate case that you have the call can be just `predict(weibull_fit, type="quantile", p=x)[1]`, with `x` - some quantile.

Note that these are just the predictions given estimated parameters - if you want to incorporate the uncertainty about the estimates as well, you will need to switch to log scale, add `se.fit=T` to the `predict` call and use that to calculate the confidence intervals for the predicted times. Something like:

```
pr = predict(weibull_fit, type="uquantile", p=0.5, se.fit=T)
lims = c(pr$fit[1] + 1.96*pr$se.fit[1], pr$fit[1] - 1.96*pr$se.fit[1])
lims = exp(lims)
```

should give 95 % CI for predicted median survival time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added a sample of my data, could you show me how to use `survreg` (the function you're linking to) to 1) obtain the Weibull fit and 2) plot the survival function? I managed to complete step 1), but I can't seem to complete step 2. I was hoping that `survival` would allow me to plot the survival function with confidence bounds...

Comment: @DeltaIV your solution to 1) looks fine. Please see the edit - the technical aspects have been discussed on Stack Overflow before, and I added as much as I know about the SEs for this kind of predictions. Looks like the `flexsurv` package may be more convenient, though.

Comment: I will try `flexsurv`. Thanks again! BTW, in the question I added a link to a Princeton university page which gives a short but very clear introduction to Survival Analysis. IMO, it's much better than the Wikipedia page.