# How to fit the Weibull model using nonlinear least squares in R?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, least-squares, curve-fitting

I have some data (x and y). I am using R for the analysis. The x-values are the particle sizes, the y-values are CPFT - cumulative percent finer than. When I plot the x against y, I think a Weibull Model could be worth to try to fit. Therefore, I would like to find Weibull parameters which are convergent to the CPFT% curve. Can anybody give me a hint on how could I approach that or refer to some nice literature?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it essential that you use "nonlinear least squares"?  If so, why?

Comment: does this help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317435/fit-a-weibull-distribution-to-right-censored-data

Comment: @whuber thank you first of all. To your question: "nonlinear least squares" because I was reading this https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/curve-fitting-and-distribution-fitting.html#d119e1798 and thats why I wrote so.

Comment: The question is likely offtopic. However, if you import the survival package in R, `survreg` fits models to Weibull distributed outcomes (usually time to event, but they can be anything).

Comment: If you post a link to the data, I can try to verify your stated assumption by fitting the data to a Weibull equation and report the results.

Comment: Thank you for the reference: it highlights the distinction between curve-fitting a "Weibull model" and fitting a Weibull *distribution.*  This would become clearer if you would include a description of your data in your question.

Comment: If you want to find a statistical distribution to fit the data, post a link to the data and I can try my online statistical distribution fitter - it tries all of the 80+ continous statistical distributions in scipy. If you would like to test it yourself, the URL is http://zunzun.com/StatisticalDistributions/1/

Comment: @whuber thank you very much. The x-values are the particle sizes, the y-values are CPFT - cumulative percent finer than. When I plot the x against y, I think a Weibull Model could be worth to try to fit. Therefore, I would like to find a Weibull parameters which could converge to the CPFT curve. But I am not sure how could I do it.

Comment: @learner `help("SSweibull")` and the last example there in particular?